# Process engraved text for OCR

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am working on these images to read the VIN number from the bottom of the car.
[image]
[image]

Before i proceed with the OCR, i am trying to process the images some how.

```
image = cv2.imread(imgpath)

# Convert To gray scale
imagegray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Edge Detection since it is engraved
high_thresh, thresh_im = cv2.threshold(imagegray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
low_thresh = 0.5*high_thresh
imagecanny = cv2.Canny(imagegray, low_thresh, high_thresh)

# Dilation
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
imagedilated = cv2.dilate(imagecanny, kernel, iterations = 1)
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
imageeroded = cv2.erode(imagedilated, kernel, iterations = 1)
```

And this is what i have so far.

[image]

There are additional challenges in the images that i have, such as:-

1. Not all the images are having horizontal orientation -- Skew is present. Any idea how can i fix that?
2. Some engravings are deep while some are shallow, How can deal with that?
3. Assume that these images were being taken from a photo camera.

I am bit of a newbie in this field. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't deal with graphics but perhaps I can say at least something. I downloaded your pics and tried to adjust the colors in your image manually in my favourite photo editor. To make the text even, I applied grayscale and played with Gamma correction and Contrast. It gave me nothing until I cropped the images to a narrow strip, like this:

[image: cropped image]

After this, adjustments work much better. Therefore my advice would be to require as little graphic data as possible to avoid such interference. And you will probably want to check out some fonts that are used by various manufacturers, since here I can see different fonts. If there's not much choice, you can generate those fonts for yourself.